# Default member initializer not being set C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, object-initializers

I have the following code:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  enum class MyEnum
  {
     option1,
     option2
  }
  "Some constructors"

private:
  "Some members and the following member"
  MyEnum enum_ = MyEnum::option1;
}
```

So basically, none of the constructors are setting the `enum_` option, which is good. Because for all of them I want this value to be default set to `option1`.
The problem is that after creating `Foo` object, `option1` is not initialized for the `enum_` value. None of `option1`/`option2` is. The value is simply not initialized. I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Also, I created a public function used to retrieve this enum_ value.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: There's no issue with the code you've presented. The actual constructors and their calling site would be relevant here.

Comment: "None of option1/option2 is. The value is simply not initialized." What does that mean? How do you know it is not initialized?

Comment: You have not shown how you even created the object of class